# Runtime Error '5' Invalid procedure call or argument when running recorded macro

Tags: excel, vba

I used the wizard in Excel to import a table from SQL Server using an existing connection to the database (Data > Existing Connections > Tables).

I recorded a Macro whilst doing this as my aim is to repeat this process and import multiple tables from the database into multiple tabs in the workbook.

When I attempt to run the Macro just recorded I receive the error message:

**Run-time error '5': Invalid procedure call or argument**

```
Sub Macro1()

With ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=4, Source:=ActiveWorkbook. _
    Connections("MyServer MyDatabase Multiple Tables"), _
    Destination:=Range("$A$1")).TableObject
    .RowNumbers = False
    .PreserveFormatting = True
    .RefreshStyle = 1
    .AdjustColumnWidth = True
    .ListObject.DisplayName = "MyTable"
    .Refresh
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: 1) what line is the error on? 2)I suspect because you already placed a table into `Range("A1")` you cannot place another one there without deleting the existing one first.

Comment: Are you trying to add a ListObject with the same name as an existing ListObject?

Comment: Thanks for the responses both, I think it had something to do with the referencing multiple tables in the connection as it now works when I use a single separate connection per table. Sometimes all you need is someone to bounce a few ideas off! Thanks again